# How to parse JSON data array with random key names using Java Spring Webclient?

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing, spring-webclient

I am new to Spring Boot and APIs in general. I am having trouble parsing with parsing a JSON Get response using Java-Spring's `WebClient` where I have something like

```java
client.get().uri("/path")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(TimeTable.class)
                .collectList()
                .block();
```

where I have a class that with `@JsonProperty` that specifies the key of the key-value pair but I don't know how to parse it if the fields have random identifier names rather than a set key every time. It works when I know what the key value is going to be, but for random ones, I'm not quite sure how to approach it using `WebClient`.

```json
[{
        "4f471d13-8842-45ba-8f3b-2f7fd0977b47PlaceA": "09:35 AM",
        "6edc3d0a-ce4e-4c02-a4a8-425fbf77d509PlaceB": "09:43 AM",
        "5e4bf15a-f858-479c-b9c3-7ce8b32322ddPlaceC": "09:45 AM",
        "2bd5bd43-8aef-49d8-8cba-f999cba41ec6PlaceD": "09:47 AM",
        "ebb3e72a-fa1f-4299-87b8-4dd099369d11PlaceE": "09:55 AM"
},

... //and so on ]
```

I've looked into some things like `@JsonIgnoreProperties` or annotations but I can't find anything that deals with `WebClient` and the `Mono` and `Flux` things I can't get a grasp of it to make sense of it.

Comment: This can be parsed to `Map<String, String>`

Comment: Does the JSON include only that data or other fields as well?

Comment: @JoãoDias, yes this is pretty much all of the JSON. I'm not entirely sure how well the Map<String,String> works but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> list = 
     objectMapper.readValue(new File("your-json.json"), new TypeReference<>(){});
```

So the following should work with your `WebClient`:

```java
client.get().uri("/path")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {})
                .collectList()
                .block();
```

Comment: @VietNguyen, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.